# HTML Select Option, text formatting

Tags: html

Do any of the modern browsers support any type (any type at all) of internal text formatting (so that part of a single option is formatting differentially). Different side, colour, strength, subscript, anything.

So far it seems that Chrome, at least, just deletes any tags put inside of option tags.

I am looking for something to accomplish this style of result (without having to deal with canvases):

```
<option value="8470621">Corey Perry <i>Anaheim Mighty Ducks</i></option>
```

OR

```
<option value="8474141"><b>Patrick Kane</b> Chicago Blackhawks</option>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is currently no support for nested HTML tags within options. The closest formatting element you can use is [`<optgroup>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) which will group options into sections.

What you could do is use a javascript replacement like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to style the elements. It isn't native, but it does support HTML.

Answer (score 3):

As the specification ["4.10.12 The option element"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) states is the content model of an `<option>`-element [text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#text-content) only.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

As you can see on  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option):

> Permitted content: Text with eventually escaped characters (like &eacute;).

There are alternatives combining other tags, but not *select* and *option*.

---

For further reading:

- [Select boxes with HTML inside each option](http://www.oshuamoreno.com/2009/09/select-boxes-with-html-inside-each-option/).
- [jQuery .customSelect()](http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/)
- [A custom select for @twitter bootstrap using button dropdown.](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Answer (score 0):

I found this method to overlay text in list, but it probably will not help with  :)

```
var result ="";
$.each(text.split(""), function () {
result += this + "\u20EB";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a javascript/css solution on https://methodfish.com/Projects/MFSelector/docs/README that takes markdown input and fakes a drop down on screen to match

[image]