# Edit style for :selected option shown in select box

Tags: html, jquery, css, tailwind-css

I have not found a solution for styling the selected option inside a `<select>` tag.

**Example:**

```html
<select class="cursor-pointer min-w-[160px] custom-black rounded-sm border border-[#d6dce2] focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-[#d6dce2] font-bold px-4 text-sm py-2.5">
  <option selected disabled hidden>Edit status</option>
  <option value="1">Status1</option>
  <option value="2">Status2</option>
  <option value="3">Status3</option>
  <option value="4">Status4</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to change the `font-style` to `italic` only for "Edit status" option.

The problem is that when I apply 'italic' to the `<select>` tag, it applies it for all options. [Select tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52YIN.png)

Adding `italic` just to this option does not work at all.

Maybe it's possible using jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

I am not well versed in jQuery, perhaps someone can help you there, but the short answer is there is no way of styling select options.

#### Long(er) Answer:

`<option>` elements are styled by your OS -not the browser- so you cannot nest other elements or style them. The [Mozilla Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) state:

> If you really need full control over the option styling, you'll have to either use some kind of library to generate a custom control, or build your own custom control...

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389787/html-select-option-text-formatting) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element) for other questions like this, and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Advanced_form_styling) for advanced style tips; maybe you can find an alternative to select, or [design your own dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_dropdowns.asp) with CSS.

Hopefully that helps you out.